# Javascript code with eventListener does't work for a video button-control-system

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle, event-listener

somebody sent me a code and I tried to run it. The problem is that the Javascript-file is not working properly. The result has to be a button-control-system for my video. I hope someone could take a look at it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dfdfs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Simplified the markup a little, less is more -->
<div id="p1">
  <a href="#/" id='b1' class='play'> </a>
  <video id="v1">
            <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* This container wraps neatly around 
|| the video's width
*/

#p1 {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;

}


/* This is to make the button an overlay */

#b1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: rgba(0, 255, 255, .3);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* These two rulsets use  simple HTML entities
|| for play/pause buttons
*/

.play::after {
  content: '\25b6';
}

.pause::after {
  content: '\23f8';
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Reference button and container
var btn1 = document.getElementById('b1');
var pyr1 = document.getElementById('p1');

// When button is clicked...
btn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  // Reference video
  var vid1 = document.getElementById('v1');

  // Conditions based on state: paused
  if (vid1.paused) {
    vid1.play();
  } else {
    vid1.pause();
  }
  /* Whatever the new state is doesn't matter if...
  || we have either .play or .pause class on button
  || previously and that both classes will toggle
  || at the same time.
  */
  btn1.classList.toggle('play');
  btn1.classList.toggle('pause');
}, false);

// If the mouse leaves the area of container...
pyr1.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {

  // If the button has the class .pause...
  if (btn1.classList.contains('pause')) {

    // set it's opacity to 0
    btn1.style.opacity = 0;

    // and make it fade away
    btn1.style.transition = '1s ease';
  }
}, false);

// If the mouse enters the container's area...
pyr1.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {

  // if the button has the class .pause...
  if (btn1.classList.contains('pause')) {

    // set it's opacity to 1  
    btn1.style.opacity = 1;

    // and make it fade in
    btn1.style.transition = '1s ease';
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: what exactly isnt working?

Comment: The script is executed before the DOM is ready. Move the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the page, right before the `</body>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you uploaded works fine ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8855ka11/)).

As Andreas mentioned move your script tags 
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>` 
to the end of your html file.